# Strip blank <p> tags from WordPress post Export

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hubspot

I'm trying to export all my posts in WordPress to integrate the same in HubSpot COS.

Though I have a some issues in formatting of posts.

There are a few `<p>`tags, which I want to strip.

Here's a DOM screenshot of a post.

[image]

The `<p>` tags without any content needs to stripped off.

The issue I'm having in HubSpot is, HubSpot creates the entry excerpt as the first paragraph of the post. Since my first paragraph is blank there is no excerpt in HubSPot.

Thoughts on tackling this?

Comment: `str_replace` http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex

```
    $content=preg_replace("/<p[^>]*>\s*<\/p>/isU","", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hubspot does not use the first paragraph as the excerpt

You can select were you want your excerpt to end by going to the blog editor, moving your cursor to the line where you want your excerpt to end, then click

Insert > Read More Separator

Done

Comment: HubSpot by default uses first paragraph as the excerpt if you have checked show summary. And exporting a correct format is better than manually changing the read more separator for 400+ posts.